# Which NavigationBar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

RN currently has 2 official and a few community developed NavigationBars.
After reading the [Navigator comparison](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator-comparison.html) it seems that Navigator is the favoured navigation controller implementation (superseding NavigatorIOS), as it allows decoupling the bar from the navigation logic.

**But which navigation bar to use with it?**

To my knowledge the main contenders are:

- [Navigator.NavigationBar](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/CustomComponents/Navigator/NavigatorNavigationBar.js)
- [https://github.com/Kureev/react-native-navbar.js](https://github.com/Kureev/react-native-navbar)

Both get the job done, but what are the pros/cons of using one over the other?

Cheers :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what i've come to find out after playing with the Navigator.

Kureev's react-native-navbar is good if you want to quickly implement a navigation bar that looks similar to NavigatorIOS but with more functionality. The only thing you have to watch out for is the way that he has implemented the actual navbar. You'll notice in his example that he renders the navbar above the content and wraps it in a view, which makes the navbar a "per page basis." So when you push or pop a view the nav bar will change with the view. Currenty there is an issue addressing this thought (#62)

The Navigator component is pretty simple to use. Using the prop navigationBar you can create a consistent navbar that persists on state changes. The one pain i've found, is the navigation bar gets put below the rendered content, so you'll have to use some styling to get it to the top if thats where you want it.

To Sum up:

- if you want quick and easy navigation use Kureev's
- If you want more flexibility and the ability to do control more of you navigation bar, create a navbar component and use Navigators navigationBar prop.
- And dont underestimate the examples from the React Native Team. [Navigator examples](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Examples/UIExplorer/Navigator)

Comment: Thanks Russell, great answer. I found that the RN's own Navigator and Navigator.NavigationBar are fine for pretty much everything I've thrown at them. 
As for your issue with it being rendered beneath content, I've figured out a fix (ironically) based on examples from Kureev's react-native-navbar. I can upload a gist later for you. :)

Comment: Yeah using Navigator.NavigationBar is a little easier, I tried to implement my own custom nav bar but I ended up using the TabBarIOS example in the Navigator examples. But id be interested to know what you ended up doing.